# jquery validate - pass in rules as an array?

Tags: jquery

Im using jquery.validate but im passing in my rules as an array, is this possible? It doesnt seem to work, can anyone point me in the right directions?

Thanks!

```
rules:{
            for (var i=0;i<myRules.length;i++)
            { 
                myRules[i]:{
                    required = true;
                }
            }
        },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot have statements inside an object literal.

```
var rules = {};
for(var i = 0; i < myRules.length; i++) {
    rules[myRules[i]] = {
        required: true
    };
}
```

Then use `rules: rules` in the object you pass to the validator.